# Cutomers are not showing in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, migration

After migrating website from Magento 1 to Magento 2 Customers are imported but not showing up in customer grid. I added customer manually but the result is same. New customers show up on the dashboard but not in customers section.

I already reindex but no no luck.

I already did

```
update indexer_state set status = 'invalid' where status != 'valid'
```

Then run:

```
php -f bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running following commands in same order;

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
```

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

```
chmod 777 -R var pub generated
```